# Not able to deploy the war in tomcat server in local

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am not able deploy the war file. I am getting the below error while starting the server. When i start the Apache tomcat outside it running fine but i want to configure with eclipse for debugging.

```
        [2018-02-19 09:32:20:437] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader :initWebApplicationContext :: Context initialization failed ::(ContextLoader.java:331) [localhost-startStop-1] 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceDirectory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/coreContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userBO' while setting bean property 'bizMap' with key [TypedStringValue: value [user], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userBO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userBOTarget' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userBOTarget' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDAO' while setting bean property 'userDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateTemplate' while setting bean property 'hibernateTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)


        ... 72 more
    Feb 19, 2018 9:32:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceDirectory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/coreContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userBO' while setting bean property 'bizMap' with key [TypedStringValue: value [user], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userBO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userBOTarget' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userBOTarget' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDAO' while setting bean property 'userDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateTemplate' while setting bean property 'hibernateTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:384)
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="userBO"
                class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
                <property name="proxyInterfaces"
                    value="com.sp.cms.sfdist.biz.UserBO" />
                <property name="target">
                    <ref local="userBOTarget" />
                </property>
            </bean>
            <bean id="userBOTarget" class="com.sp.cms.sfdist.biz.UserBOImpl">
                <property name="userDAO">
                    <ref local="userDAO" />
                </property>
                <property name="companyDAO">
                    <ref local="companyDAO" />
                </property>
                <property name="licenseDAO">
                    <ref local="licenseDAO" />
                </property>
                <property name="productDAO">
                    <ref local="productDAO" />
                </property>
        </bean>
```

coreContext.xml

```
<!--  Begin Service Directory definition -->

    <bean id="serviceDirectory"
        class="com.sp.cms.core.ServiceDirectory">
        <property name="bizMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="user" value-ref="userBO" />
                <!--entry key="deal" value-ref="dealBO" /-->
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--  End of ServiceDirectory definition -->
```

Comment: Seems you didn't set up the database connection properly and it's causing a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You need to provide more information i.e. the content of your `applicationContext.xml` and how your `DAO`s are setup. The error clearly states that it cannot create a `Bean` because of a null reference.

Comment: @Andreas: I added database connection in conf/context.xml in apache tomcat folder.